# PuTTY command line automate serial commands from file

Tags: batch-file, serial-port, command-line-interface, putty, plink

I am trying to connect to a serial port and send a series of commands from a file.

Firstly I have mananged to connect via the following:

> PuTTY.exe -serial COM3 -sercfg 57600,8,n,1,N

E.g. I have a file called commands.txt with a series of serial commands I wished to be sent.

I tried the following however it failed to work:

> PuTTY.exe -serial COM3 -sercfg 57600,8,n,1,N -m commands.txt

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable answer?

Comment: @Jeremy Sachadee's answer should do the trick if you're having similar issues.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this :

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type commands.txt') do PuTTY.exe -serial COM3 -sercfg 57600,8,n,1,N -m %%a
```

Comment: The 'commands.txt' file shall include list of file paths in which the actual commands are placed.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which I have used to regularly send commands to a device uses a combination of [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and [Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/).

For the initial setup, configure a PuTTY session and save it. In my case I named is Oasis.

The following Autohotkey function can send a command to the already open PuTTY session. If PuTTY is not open it will start the saved session. `oasis_putty_name()` is the name of the PuTTY window once it's open, it will depend on the COM port selected. `location_putty()` is the location of the PuTTY executable. Both of these can be hard coded but I wanted to keep the variables separate from the functions.

```
; Oasis Check --------------------------------------------------
oasis_check(){
putty_name := oasis_putty_name()

; Start PuTTY if it's not already running
IfWinNotExist, %putty_name%
{
    putty := location_putty()
    Run %putty% -load Oasis

    Sleep,1000
}

; Format Time Stamp
FormatTime, TimeString,,yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss

; Record Oasis Values
ControlSend, , %TimeString%{ENTER}, %putty_name%
Sleep, 2000
ControlSend, , all?{ENTER}, %putty_name%
}
```

The frequency of execution can be controlled with another Autohotkey script or, as in my case, with the Windows Task Manager.